# Converting multiple Bools to String for CoreData storage and back again

Tags: swift, string, boolean

I have a situation where I have 20-30 true/false questions that need to be stored in CoreData. Instead of creating 20-30 different objects in CoreData I would like to convert the answers to a String (or other if easier) so I can save as one Object. I have a working model, but feel like I took the long way around. I'm sure there's a more efficient way of doing this, it gets dicey when adding all results. I'm not the most experienced, so I may be missing something basic, excuse me if that is the case. Thanks for the help!

Conversion to save to CoreData as String

```
struct ConversionForCD: View {
    @State var firstAnswer: Bool = false
    @State var secondAnswer: Bool = false
    @State var thirdAnswer: Bool = false
    @State var fourthAnswer: Bool = false
    
    @State var coreDataObject: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Toggle("First Question", isOn: $firstAnswer)
            Toggle("Second Question", isOn: $secondAnswer)
            Toggle("Third Question", isOn: $thirdAnswer)
            Toggle("Fourth Question", isOn: $fourthAnswer)
            
            Button("Save To CoreData") {
                saveToCoreData()
            }
            Text(coreDataObject)
        }
    }
    func boolToString(first: Bool,
                      second: Bool,
                      third: Bool,
                      fourth: Bool) -> String {
        let firstString = first.intValue()
        let secondString = second.intValue()
        let thirdString = third.intValue()
        let fourthString = fourth.intValue()

        return "\(firstString)"+"\(secondString)"+"\(thirdString)"+"\(fourthString)"
    }
    
    func saveToCoreData() {
        coreDataObject = boolToString(
            first: firstAnswer,
            second: secondAnswer,
            third: thirdAnswer,
            fourth: fourthAnswer)
    }
}

extension Bool: IntValue {
    func intValue() -> Int {
        if self {
            return 1
        }
        return 0
    }
}
```

Display fetched results from CoreData (Edited)

```
struct ConversionFromCD: View {
    @State var coreDataString: String = "1001"
    @State var result: [Bool] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Button("Displaye Results From CD") {
                result = stringToBool(boolString: coreDataString)
            }
            ForEach(result, id: \.self) { value in
                Text(value.description)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func stringToBool(boolString: String) -> Array<Bool> {
        for ch in boolString {
            result.append((String(ch) as NSString).boolValue)
        }
         return result
    }

extension String {
var boolValue: Bool {
    return (self as NSString).boolValue
}}
```

Comment: At least consider using `[Bool]` instead of tuples. A lot easier to handle a variable number of values that way. A simple loop will handle the array instead of adding a line for each tuple element.

Comment: This looks like a long term nightmare, separating the bool from the question/identifier will make the values meaningless in the long term. It is incredibly fragile code with multiple points of potential failure.

Comment: @HangarRash I've edited the ConversionFromCD to take your advice, thank you

Answer (score 0):

A reasonable solution is to encode/decode the `Bool` array from and to JSON.

In the `NSManagedObject` subclass add a Core Data attribute `stateString`

```
@NSManaged public var stateString: String
```

and a computed property

```
var toggleStates : [Bool] {
    get { return (try? JSONDecoder().decode([Bool].self, from: Data(stateString.utf8))) ?? [] }
    set {
        let data = try! JSONEncoder().encode(newValue)
        stateString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "[]"
    }
}
```

Saving the toggle states is pretty simple

```
myObject.toggleStates = [firstAnswer, secondAnswer, thirdAnswer, fourthAnswer]
```

where `myObject` is an instance of the mentioned `NSManagedObject` subclass